# What is the maximum size of the JSONArray "results" googleapi returns?

Tags: json, google-maps, arrays

I get a JSONArray as a response to this url:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=49.658355,10.423788&sensor=false&language=de.

However, the size of the "results" JSONArray differs from the results I get, when the url contains the coordinates of the Berlin city. So I need to know how long the "results" can be.

Comment: The maximium-length AFAIK is not defined somewhere. There e.g. is an example in the API-documentation with 12 results. For which purposes do you need this information?

Comment: I need to parse "location" array in the "geometry" array and get the latitude and the longitude. This step needs to be done for every index of "results" array. But because the length of results vary, I have to know how long it can maximumly be, so I can adjust the index in each case.
P.S. Could you please post the link to that api in your comment? I could not find it!

Comment: The example can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding  (inspect the 12 results here: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3D40.714224%2C-73.961452). However, the results-property of the returned  JSON is an array, when you need to know the size of the returned results-array you may simply access the length of this array (how exactly depends on the used language)